# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(L)$

Tags: limits, proof-verification, continuity

If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, if $a≤x_n≤b$ for each $n$, and if $\lim x_n = L$, prove that $\lim f(x_n)=f(L)$

To start with, I have already proven in a previous assignment that if if $a≤x_n≤b$ for each $n$ and $\lim x_n = L$, then $a≤L≤b$: From the definition of the limit of a sequence, since $\lim x_n = L$, there exists $n>N$ such that $\lvert x_n-L\rvert<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$. Suppose that $L>b$, and set $\epsilon=L-b$, which is now positive.  Since $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$ then $ x_n>L-\epsilon=L-(L-b)=b$, i.e. $ x_n >b$, which contradicts the fact that $a≤x_n≤b$. Similarly it is shown that $L<a$ contradicts the conditions, hence $a≤L≤b$.

Since $a≤L≤b$ and $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $f$ is continuous on $L$, and by the definition of continuity there exists for every $\epsilon>0$ a number $k>0$ so that $\rvert x_n-L \lvert<k \Rightarrow \rvert f(x_n)-f(L)\lvert<\epsilon$.

The following is where I am uncertain if I understand things correctly:

Since $\lim x_n=L$, or rather, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L$, then from the definition of limit there must exist a $\delta>0$ such that $0<\rvert n-\infty \lvert<\delta\Rightarrow\rvert x_n-L|<k$. But since I already showed that $\rvert x_n-L \lvert<k \Rightarrow \rvert f(x_n)-f(L)\lvert<\epsilon$, it follows that  $0<\rvert n-\infty \lvert<\delta\Rightarrow \rvert f(x_n)-f(L)\lvert<\epsilon$, which by the definition of limit is an expression for the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(L)$, which is what I set out to prove.

I feel a bit uneasy about the usage of some terms in the last part, specifically, should I not be relying on the definition of the limit of a *sequence* rather than that of a function, or am I just overthinking things here?

Answer (score 4):

When you said $|n-\infty|<\delta$, this expression doesn't make sense, because $\infty$ is not a real number. The definition of $lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L$ is

$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}$, $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$, $\forall n\geq n_0$

(That one on the second paragraph of your proof)

Given $\epsilon>0$ you need to prove $\exists n_0$ such that $|f(x_n)-f(L)|<\epsilon$, $\forall n\geq n_0$. 
And you know:

$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists n_1$ such that $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$, $\forall n\geq n_1$,

$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x_n-L|<k \Rightarrow |f(x_n)-f(L)|<\epsilon$

**Hint:** you can pick the "first" $\epsilon$ as small as you want.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yes, I felt the infinity part was a bit odd to rely on, but I didn't see another way at that time :p
Anyway, by the first of the two statements, I know that the exists $N$ so that when $n>N, |x_n-L|<δ$. Now, I set $δ=k$. But by the second statement, when $|x_n-L|<k, |f(x_n)-f(L)|<ϵ$. Hence, there exists $N$ so that when $n>N, |f(x_n)-f(L)|<ϵ$
Is this correct?

Comment: @Llama_guy Yes, you're right.